# How to read a specific line from a text file in Pascal

Tags: pascal

So I'm making a program where the user enters some lines and saves them in a file, then we get he gets to choose what line he wrote to crypt it.
Means he'll enter a number, let's say 2 referring to line 2 in the text file.
The question is, how to get that specific line from the text file?
Seek obviously doesn't work with text files !

```
Procedure cryptProcess( Var msgFile, cryptFile : Text; N : Integer);
Var
  pNumber : Integer;
Begin
  Writeln('Select a phrase to crypt [Number : ',N,'] : ');
  Readln( pNumber );
  Reset( msgFile );
  For i:= 1 To N Do
    Begin
      If ( i = pNumber ) Then
        Begin
          Readln( msgFile, tempVar2 );
          Writeln( i );
          Writeln( tempVar2 );
        End;
    End;
  Close( msgFile );
End;
```

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question.

Comment: Sorry, there I edited my post, first time posting here didn't think it would require much of explaination, that Writeln( i ); is for me to check if the line we stopped at is the same as pNumber ( the number the user entered ) and it matches. But when I try to read that line into the tempVar2 it reads the first line, not the line the user selected

Comment: OK, I spotted the problem almost immediately; what I strongly recommend you do is "desk check" your code - that is, pretend that you are the computer, and "execute" the code exactly like the computer would - don't try to "interpret" the meaning of the code. If you do that, I think you'll find your error very quickly.

Comment: To be honest the way I see it makes sense for me, I looped through the lines and I checked if the line number and user number match, if true then load the line into the tempVar.. that's my problem I can't spot it, and tbh I'm doing so for a school project and I'm not that experienced with pascal !, was hoping to find an easier way to find a specific line ( knowing that the line number is known as it's entered by the user )

Comment: I've been already trying to tweak for hours, tried various methods, but nothing seems to work with me, since Seek and FilePos doesn't work with Text files so I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pascal can only process text files sequentially - in order to read and use line *n* from a text file, you *must* read (and likely discard) lines 1 through *n* - 1. Your existing code never actually reads text from the file unless the user happens to request the first line.

What you want to do is replace

```
  For i:= 1 To N Do
    Begin
      If ( i = pNumber ) Then
        Begin
          Readln( msgFile, tempVar2 );
          Writeln( i );
          Writeln( tempVar2 );
        End;
    End;
```

with

```
    For i:= 1 To pNumber Do
      ReadLn(msgFile, tempVar2);
    WriteLn(pNumber);
    WriteLn(tempVar2);
```

This reads the first `pNumber` lines from the file - that is, it reads up to the line that you want, and no further - and then prints the number and the line.

Comment: Yes, I did that eariler as one of my attempts but that would read all the lines and output them all, meanwhile I only want to output a specific line only, not the ones before it nor the ones after it

Comment: Then you didn't do what I have here; this code will read through the file but only print the last line read.

Comment: Ah I see.. I wrote your code between Begin and End; now thats why, but what's the difference? shouldn't Begin and End doesn't affect the code inside?

Comment: `Begin...End;` establishes a block, which is semantically equivalent to a single statement. So, if you bracket the `Readln(...); Writeln(...); Writeln(...);` with a `Begin...End;`, you make them all a single statement, and if that's the single statement that a `For...` executes, you'll get the effect you describe.